# How to update existing Phonegap Build app with Phonegap CLI

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am just moving from Phonegap 2.9.0 to 3.2.0 and I am using Phonegap Build. However, I am struggling with the update of my existing apps in the Phonegap Build.
When I login through the Phonegap CLI to Phonegap dev site and I type

```
phonegap remote build android ios
```

the app gets built indeed but the CLI creates another app into my Phonegap Build account and can't find the existing app by matching the id of the app from the config.xml file to the ids of the apps that are already created.

I found some config file at .cordova/config.json where you can set explicitly the app id that needs to be updated but it is generated again every time I run the build command.

Is there a way for the CLI to automatically find the app that needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this PhoneGap blog post http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/28/phonegap-320-released/, it says that PhoneGap Build will be updated to support 3.2 in roughly 1-2 weeks after v3.2 itself was released, and after Googling it a bit further (where I came across this post too), it seems PhoneGap build may not have been updated to support 3.2 just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the first few lines of your config.xml files match with the updated app's config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.yourdomain.app" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>You app name</name>
```

The most important bit is the id attribute.